# How to load a font only once ? (TS / Three.JS)

Tags: typescript, three.js

So, I would like to create 20 text blocks (using the same font).

The new TextGeometry sends an error if the font is not loaded yet.

Currently, I put every

```
new THREE.TextGeometry(this.text, {
    font: Object(response) as THREE.Font
} as THREE.TextGeometryParameters);
```

inside :

```
let fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();    
fontLoader.load('/fonts/my_font.json', response => {
```

This method is very inefficient because the font is loaded 20 times (once for each new text). It slows down the execution (annoying when I make tests).

I would like to load the font only once and save it in a var, but I don't know how to wait until it's loaded to generate the TextGeometry.

I guess that it has something to do with Observables ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post more code that shows why are fonts being loaded 20 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can do it like this:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onLoad = function() { // when all resources are loaded
  init();
  render();
}

var font = null;
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader(manager);
loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/droid/droid_serif_bold.typeface.json', function(response) {
  font = response;
});
```

and in the `init()`:

```
function init(){
    // create instances of scene, camera and renderer
    ...
    function setText(text, position) { // actually, here you can have any parameters you want for your text
        textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, {
            font: font,...
    }
}
```

The main idea is all resources first, the other stuff later.

About [THREE.LoadingManager()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/o94z3u8b/) example

Comment: I thought about this but my text blocks are created in different files, at different times.

The best idea I had was to make a "queue" with the calls for new texts, and treat the queue in the async load block.

But I thought that there surely was a better solution.

Comment: so load all your resources first (fonts, textures etc.), using THREE.LoadingManager() with loaders, then, when resources are done, run the main sequence (init, fill scene with objects (creating block of text and so on), animation / render)

Comment: ive read this a couple of times and still dont understand it. Is the manager really needed here? There is already a callback in the original question, why can't all 20 text entities be initialized there?

Comment: @pailhead The manager needed in situation, when you have to load many resources. And you're right, as you have to load just one font, then it's enough to use the callback function of the `THREE.FontLoader()`. Thus you can rid the manager off and put `init(); render();` in the callback function of the font loader.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out what the question was. Like, those two blocks of code could have been written as one without the "and then inside" comment and would have probably been clearer. Are there many entities being made with one font, or many entities being made with multiple fonts. If 20 entities then using a manager doesn't really help at all, you're going to have to load all 20 entities. If it's one font, and 20 entities, you dont need the manager. The reason why i mention this is to make it more clear for someone else reading this. The question is pretty clear "how to load once"

Comment: tl:dr: loading something once, kinda implies that there should be no manager, since you do get the callback with any loader's `load()` method.

Comment: @pailhead As I said, you're right ) I don't argue about not using manager, when you need to load just one resource. The accent is on the idea about loading resource(s) first (with or without a manager)

Comment: I know, i'm not trying to argue you, i'm trying to figure out if we should edit the question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138273/discussion-between-prisoner849-and-pailhead).